# Moving existing media items to new upload path structure not updating full URL path

Tags: media, uploads

Have been developing a site and noticed that all of the media files were being saved in the default WP year/month/day rule in the `wp-content/uploads` directory. I decided to change this to `assets` and unchecked the option to store these in the date format.

End goal here is to bring over all of the existing media to use that new path. I extracted all of the sub-folders into a flat list of files and then copied them over to the `assets` directory.

Then, I tried editing the GUID for attachments to the new location -- still, no dice. Right now, it's referencing those old files as `assets/2012/08/01` instead of the new format.

I've verified the option for storing media files in the date subdirectories is unchecked -- is this stored in a transient/cache somewhere that I can reset? I'm more than comfortable going through and running the needed SQL queries to update any post content with these in them, but a bit confused on why the URLs on the front-end are not updating to just `assets`). Thanks!

*Update*

New files are being stored just in `/assets` and not the sub-date folders... really confused on these old file paths not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path, including the date directories, is stored in the postmeta for the attachment's post, using the `_wp_attached_file` meta_key.

If you examine the data for that key, you'll find that the meta_value is `2012/08/example.jpg` or something similar to that. This is used to build the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your dashboard settings > media
wp-admin/options-media.php
under the file uploads heading place your new path in the associated field

Comment: Already done that as described in my question - the old file URLs are not updating on the front-end (even with a GUID update via the DB). Maybe they're stored in a transient somewhere based on the original file's creation date and then based on when that URL option is saved and new files are uploaded, take on that new URL path.